# My internet is really slow

Tags: wireless

I have been trying to fix this problem for a while now and i still can't, so I hope you guys can help me.
The problem is that whenever I try and use Ubuntu or any other Linux Distro, my internet is really slow. I am using a TP-Link TL-WN822N (Version 3). While using windows it as fast as it can be, however when using Linux it is extremely slow as I cannot download applications or even general updates.

Comment: If you mean that Apt-related stuff ("download applications" and "general updates") is slow, that's not necessarily due to any problems with your Internet connection. It could just be that the servers for Apt-related stuff are slow. Have you tried [an Internet speed test](http://www.speedtest.net/) on both Windows and Ubuntu?

Comment: A speediest.net result would really help.